# Convertir String a Imagen

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

esta vez vengo con una pregunta, tengo un string sacado desde un campo imgen de una base de datos quiero saber como convertir ese string en imagen. Ayuda por favor, este es el string en visual Basic, por cuestion del limite permitido aqui faltan caracteres.

```
Dim s As String = "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"
```

La Base de datos en la que esta almacenada la Imagen es SQL Server 2000 y el tipo de Datos Es IMAGE.

Comment: Hacen falta datos: por ejemplo en que tipo de base de datos estas guardando, decir "campo imagen de una base de datos" es muy amplio.

Answer (score 1):

Si es un string base 64, usa:

```
Private Function String2Bitmap(ByVal cad as String) as Bitmap
  Dim ib() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(cad)
  Dim bm as Bitmap = Nothing
  Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(ib, 0, ib.Length)
    ms.Write(ib, 0, ib.Length)
    bm = Bitmap.FromStream(ms)
  End Using
  Return bm
End Function
```

Comment: La Base de datos en la que esta almacenada la Imagen es SQL Server 2000 y el tipo de Datos Es IMAGE